# Open Graph Localization

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to localize objects in Facebook's OpenGraph?

My specific goal is having French/English users able to like the same URL or Graph object, while having local-specific descriptions appear in their timelines. So far the only way I can achieve this is having two separate graph nodes, effectively dividing the number of likes in half.

I've attempted to provide English and French versions of my page, with the French version using the English page's URL as its canonical URL, but this results in the French user's having the English page's title/description appear in their timeline.

Is there any way of having both French and English versions of the page while having one shared "like" count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The detailed docs you want are here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/

In short, you'll want to provide a primary locale in the `og:locale` tag, and then alternate locales in the `og:locale:alternate` tag. For each alternate locale, the FB scraper will rescrape the page, but pass in the alternate locale in the `fb_locale` query string parameter.  You should take this query string parameter and provide the appropriate locale-specific meta data.

Comment: how can I localize an object that is not a web page?